# Continue to work while experimenting a change

Tags: git

I experiment an improvement of an algorithm, and committed it to local git repository. I want to test the revised algorithm and at the same time, work on another feature. When I'm comfortable with the revised algorithm, I then merge it to master. How would be the workflow?

If I branch from the algorithm branch, when I merge the feature branch, the algorithm change will also be brought in. How can I merge the feature branch without the algorithm change?

Comment: dont branch from algorithm branch. Checkout from master branch.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar  I want to test the revised algorithm and at the same time, work on another feature.

Comment: Implement them on different branches forked from master branch. Keep switching them to whichever thing you work at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I would also branch from the master, because logically your alternative algorithm branch is not part of the master branch. If you have some complex relationships with rest of the program vs. algorithm it would be better to make a whole another beta-(master) branch and keep your beta-branchmaster otherwise identical to original master. (Assuming it's the original master branch you want to work with besides tweaking your algorithm).